# What is the most effective way to format ttk styling in Python?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, ttk

I am working on a fairly large tkinter/ttk application. I originally defined widget styling and formatting in the widget declaration. This was pretty cumbersome, and I had a ton of lines that looked something like this:

`idLabel = Label(self, text='ID', fg=self.labelfg, bg=self.labelbg, font=self.labelfont, height=1, anchor='sw', highlightbackground=self.labelfg)`

At a certain size this became really difficult to maintain. I hadn't tried the ttk Style class before, but I spent a lot of time converting from tkinter to ttk, and I'm running into many similar problems. I thought I would be able to have all my styling in one place, but it seems like most of it still has to be done inline. Currently I have a styling class that looks like this:

```
...
self.style.theme_settings(current_theme,
                               {'.':
                                   {'configure':
                                        {'background'       : 'black',
                                         'selectbackground' : 'blue',
                                         'selectforeground' : 'white',
                                         'fieldbackground'  : 'black',
                                         'insertbackground' : 'white',
                                         'foreground'       : 'white',
                                         'relief'           : 'flat'}},
                                'EntryTabView.TFrame':
                                   {'configure':
                                        {'background'       : 'black',
                                         'relief'           : 'sunken',
                                         'borderwidth'      : 10}},
                                'CompetitorInfoView_Label.TLabel':
                                    {'configure':
                                         {'background'      : 'black',
                                          'foreground'      : 'white',
                                          'anchor'          : 'w',
                                          'font'            : gen_font}},
...
```

This doesn't do much better because there are still options that I have to specify inline. Not to mention that there does not seem to be any useful documentation for ttk Python Styling anywhere (please point me to it if its there I have looked so deep).

My question is the following: How should I most effectively make use of the tkinter.ttk Style class?

Additionally, why is there no reliable documentation on this?

I am quite frustrated; maybe I just need to learn something other than tkinter. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code. It's not searchable and it's not able to be copied and pasted.

Comment: @BryanOakley Sorry, it was difficult to format properly in SO. I'll edit it momentarily.